# Merging CSV rows using Python2 and keeping data from a single arbitrary column

Tags: python, csv

I know there are a lot of questions on this topic but the answers aren't particularly well *explained* so it's difficult to adapt to my use case. The one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156291/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-with-python-to-merge-rows-in-a-csv-which-have-a-s) seems very promising but the syntax is rather complex and I'm having difficulty understanding and adapting it.

I have a need to convert the raw CSV output from Nessus to a standard format which essentially dumps a lot of the columns keeping only the Severity, IP addresses, and output of each finding. I've put a script together which does just that **but** if a finding is on multiple hosts/ports there is a different row for each host/port.

What I need is to merge rows based on the vulnerability name but only keeping the IP address data.

**Example input - shortened for ease**

```
High,10.10.10.10,MS12-345(this is the name),Hackers can do bad things
High,10.10.10.11,MS12-345(this is the name),Hackers can do bad things
```

**Example output**

```
High,10.10.10.10 10.10.10.11,MS12-345(this is the name),Hackers can do bad things
```

Below is my script so far. I would appreciate if you make your answer easily adaptable (read: idiot-proof) for future readers and I'm sure they would too.

**Bonus:**

Sometimes the output field is different for findings with the same name, sometimes it is the same. If you've got some time on your hands, why not help a man check for this and append in the same way as the IP addresses if there's a difference in the output?

```
import sys
import csv

def manipulate(inFile):

    with open(inFile, 'rb') as csvFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(csvFile, dialect='excel')

        # Check for multiple instances of findings and merge the rows
        # This happens when the finding is on multiple hosts/ports

        //YOUR CODE WILL GO HERE (Probably...)

        # Place findings into lists: crits, highs, meds, lows for sorting later
        crits = []
        highs = []
        meds = []
        lows = []

        for row in fileReader:

            if row[3] == "Critical":    
                crits.append(row)
            elif row[3] == "High":
                highs.append(row)
            elif row[3] == "Medium":
                meds.append(row)
            elif row[3] == "Low":
                lows.append(row)

        # Open an output file for writing
        with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outFile: 
            fileWriter = csv.writer(outFile)

            # Add in findings from lists in order of severity. Only relevant columns included
            for c in crits:
                fileWriter.writerow( (c[3], c[4], c[7], c[12]) )

            for h in highs:
                fileWriter.writerow( (h[3], h[4], h[7], h[12]) )

            for m in meds:
                fileWriter.writerow( (m[3], m[4], m[7], m[12]) )

            for l in lows:
                fileWriter.writerow( (l[3], l[4], l[7], l[12]) )


# Input validation
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'You must provide a csv file to process'
    raw_input('Example: python nesscsv.py foo.csv')
else:
    print "Working..."
    # Store filename for use in manipulate function
    inFile = str(sys.argv[1])
    # Call manipulate function passing csv
    manipulate(inFile)

print "Done!"   
raw_input("Output in output.csv. Hit return to finish.")
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused on what your expected output should be. Do you just want to remove duplicate values?

Comment: Yes and no. For each vulnerability I only want a single row. However, there is a separate row for every IP address that has that particular vulnerability so if I just delete every row with the same vulnerability I would end up with only a single IP address when it could affect any number.

Comment: So what I need to do is, for every duplicate, append the new IP address to the same entry as the one for the old IP address before dropping the row. So I end up with just one row per vuln but listing every IP address affected by that vuln.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses an OrderedDict to gather rows in a way that preserves their order while also allowing to look up any row by its vulnerability name.

```
import sys
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

def manipulate(inFile):

    with open(inFile, 'rb') as csvFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(csvFile, dialect='excel')

        # Check for multiple instances of findings and merge the rows
        # This happens when the finding is on multiple hosts/ports

        # Dictionary mapping vulns to merged rows.
        # It's ordered to preserve the order of rows.
        mergedRows = OrderedDict()

        for newRow in fileReader:
            vuln = newRow[7]
            if vuln not in mergedRows:
                # Convert the host and output fields into lists so we can easily
                # append values from rows that get merged with this one.
                newRow[4] = [newRow[4], ]
                newRow[12] = [newRow[12], ]
                # Add row for new vuln to dict.
                mergedRows[vuln] = newRow
            else:
                # Look up existing row for merging.
                mergedRow = mergedRows[vuln]
                # Append values of host and output fields, if they're new.
                if newRow[4] not in mergedRow[4]:
                    mergedRow[4].append(newRow[4])
                if newRow[12] not in mergedRow[12]:
                    mergedRow[12].append(newRow[12])

        # Flatten the lists of host and output field values into strings.
        for row in mergedRows.values():
            row[4] = ' '.join(row[4])
            row[12] = ' // '.join(row[12])

        # Place findings into lists: crits, highs, meds, lows for sorting later
        crits = []
        highs = []
        meds = []
        lows = []

        for row in mergedRows.values():

            if row[3] == "Critical":
                crits.append(row)
            elif row[3] == "High":
                highs.append(row)
            elif row[3] == "Medium":
                meds.append(row)
            elif row[3] == "Low":
                lows.append(row)

        # Open an output file for writing
        with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outFile:
            fileWriter = csv.writer(outFile)

            # Add in findings from lists in order of severity. Only relevant columns included
            for c in crits:
                fileWriter.writerow( (c[3], c[4], c[7], c[12]) )

            for h in highs:
                fileWriter.writerow( (h[3], h[4], h[7], h[12]) )

            for m in meds:
                fileWriter.writerow( (m[3], m[4], m[7], m[12]) )

            for l in lows:
                fileWriter.writerow( (l[3], l[4], l[7], l[12]) )


# Input validation
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'You must provide a csv file to process'
    raw_input('Example: python nesscsv.py foo.csv')
else:
    print "Working..."
    # Store filename for use in manipulate function
    inFile = str(sys.argv[1])
    # Call manipulate function passing csv
    manipulate(inFile)

print("Done!")
raw_input("Output in output.csv. Hit return to finish.")
```

Comment: Ya wee beauty! I suspected that this could be done using a dictionary somehow, just not experienced enough to figure it out myself. I'll give it a try now and come back to you. Sorry for the delay in response, had no connection over the weekend.